# Workflow not working while updating record

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I am working on a workflow rule

Rule Criteria

```
(Opportunity: Opportunity Record Type EQUALS Express Program,Express Post-Compliance) AND (Opportunity: StageEQUALS Awarded) AND ((Opportunity: Sub-StageEQUALS New Contract) OR (Opportunity: Sub-StageEQUALS null))
```

This is the Rule Criteria and it works while creating records with each of the Record Types,Stages and Substages.Even while keeping the substage as null it works and I have kept an immediate email alert and I receive the email immediately.

But if I update the records to meet all of these rule criteria it is not working.

Evaluation Criteria:Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Set the evaluation criteria as "**created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria**"

- For a new record, run the rule if the rule criteria is met.
- For an updated record, run the rule only if the record is changed
  from not meeting the rule criteria to meeting the rule criteria.

With this option, the rule can run multiple times per record, but it won’t run when the record edits are unrelated to the rule criteria.

For example, suppose that for an opportunity record to meet the rule criteria, the opportunity probability must be greater than 50%. If you create an opportunity with a probability of 75%, the workflow rule runs. If you edit that opportunity by changing the probability to 25%, the edit doesn't cause the rule to run. If you then edit that opportunity by changing the probability from 25% to 75%, the edit causes the rule to run. With this last edit, the rule runs, because the record is changed from not meeting the rule criteria to meeting the rule criteria.

Refer the help  [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workflow_rules_define.htm&type=5)